# How to use npm to run tests in multiple directories using wildcards

Tags: npm, mocha.js

When I use this command

```
"test": "mocha *.spec.js *.test.js test/*.spec.js test/*.test.js",
```

It runs as I want, i.e. all the test and spec files in the root (2) plus any in test/ (2).  So 4 get run.

```
  4 passing (4ms)
```

I'd like to simplify it but all my attempts have failed.  examples:

```
"test": "mocha",
"test": "mocha *.spec.js *.test.js",
"test": "mocha **/*.spec.js **/*.test.js",
"test": "mocha */*.spec.js */*.test.js",
```

but these only run 2 of the 4 tests.  2 are in root, 2 are in test/

I also tried using

```
--recursive
```

but it didn't help.

How to run all 4 with a shorter syntax using wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://mochajs.org/#the-test-directory):

> [You should *always* quote your globs in npm scripts](https://medium.com/@jakubsynowiec/you-should-always-quote-your-globs-in-npm-scripts-621887a2a784). If you use
>   double quotes, it's the shell on UNIX that will expand the glob. On
>   the other hand, if you use single quotes, the [`node-glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) module
>   will handle its expansion.

With the following structure (one `it` in each test file, `mocha@7.1.0` installed):

```
temp/
    node_modules/
    test/
        four.test.js
        three.spec.js
    one.test.js
    package-lock.json
    package.json
    two.spec.js
```

using either the script:

```
"test": "mocha '**/*.spec.js' '**/*.test.js'"
```

or:

```
"test": "mocha \"**/*.spec.js\" \"**/*.test.js\""
```

ran all four tests:

```
> temp@1.0.0 test path/to/temp
> mocha '**/*.spec.js' '**/*.test.js'



  ✓ three
  ✓ two
  ✓ one
  ✓ four

  4 passing (10ms)
```

By comparison, the unquoted version *only* runs the tests in `test/`.

---

You can simplify even further using the pattern `**/*.{spec,test}.js`; again this needs either single or double quotes in your script.